# Выборочная загрузка тайлов OSM

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

Существует ли возможность загружать тайлы OSM без POI, используя штатное API?

Comment: неужели вам чем-то поможет ответ «да» или ответ «нет»?

Answer (score 1):

У OSM нет API для получения тайлов. Вы просто подключаете картинки с определённого адреса. Поскольку это картинки — растровые изображения — то на части их разделить не получится. Так что нет.

Однако адрес картинок легко подменить, и у OpenStreetMap есть множество слоёв без POI. Например, от [MapQuest](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest#MapQuest-hosted_map_tiles). Кроме того, вы можете [настроить](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) собственный рендеринг, где, например, взять тот же стандартный стиль и убрать из него значки и подписи POI.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вариант со своим рендером однозначно предусматривает хостинг картографических данных на своём сервере, исключая возможность обработки данных OSM прямо из API налету?

Comment: При хостинге данных на своём сервере можно обновлять их ежеминутно из общей базы. Как вариант, можно подписаться на сервисы Mapbox и делать стиль в Mapbox Studio — тогда, кроме денег, вообще ничего не нужно.